# How to copy an apk into /system/ folder using adb?

Tags: android, adb, apk

While using android debug bridge remount, it changes the system folder to r/w, but 
as soon as the user tries to copy some file using  android debug bridge to the system folder it changes to read-only

Comment: Yes the device is rooted.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is not rooted, you cannot copy anything to the System or Data partitions.

With root do the following commands in a command prompt or linux shell and all should be fine:

```
    adb push fileName /data/local/tmp
    adb shell
    su
    mount -o remount, rw /system
    cp /data/local/tmp/fileName /system/folderOfYourChoise
    chmod 644 (if its an apk and you want the system to use it as a system app)
    exit (exits the su shell)
    exit (exits the adb shell)
    adb reboot (to apply and see changes on the device)
```

Comment: Mike, we tried this before the post it says that the /system folder is Read only file system.

Comment: Something is wrong with what was tried. on which command from the list i sent does it say that the system is read only? Can you post the output, please? Also, you are trying on a real device or in a emulator, like Genymotion?